# Getting " 'NoneType' object is not callable" Error While Using Classes in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, oop

I'm still new to this site, so forgive poor formatting. I'm trying to make a class for a point on a cartesian plane and a method for finding the slope of a line when given two points. However, while working on it, pycharm tells me that `Instance attribute slope(name of variable) defined outside __init__`. However when I place `self.slope` into `__init__` and assign it to run it gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Volumes/SEAGATE_for_editing/Programming/Python/graphing stuff/stuff.py", line 28, in <module>
    print(point1.slope(point2))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

How do I fix this? Here is my code. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
class Point:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

        self.y_slope = None
        self.x_slope = None
        self.slope = None

    def slope(self, other):
        self.y_slope = other.y - self.y
        self.x_slope = other.x - self.x
        self.slope = self.y_slope / self.x_slope
        return self.slope

    def dist(self, other):
        self.x_dist = other.x - self.x
        self.y_dist = other.y - self.y
        self.distance = ((self.x_dist ** 2) + (self.y_dist ** 2)) ** (1/2)
        return self.distance


point1 = Point(-2, -5)
point2 = Point(1, 1)
print(point1.slope(point2))
print(round(point1.dist(point2), 4))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the same name for an attribute `self.slope` and your method `def slope(self, other)`. The attribute shadows the method name, so when you try calling `point1.slope(...)`, it tries to call the value of the attribute which is initialized to `None`.

Pick different names for the two things and your code will work as expected.

Or, as ForceBru noticed in their answer, just don't bother with any of the `slope` or `dist` related attributes at all, the seem to be unneeded. You can use local variables in your methods instead, just name them without the `slope.` prefix.

Answer (score 4):

`point1.slope` is `None`. You set it to `None` yourself in `__init__`:

```
class Point:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        ...
        self.slope = None  # here
```

You don't really need `self.slope` here. You can return the result of division directly:

```
def slope(self, other):
    y_slope = other.y - self.y
    x_slope = other.x - self.x
    return y_slope / x_slope
```

There's also no need for `self.x_slope` and `self.y_slope` as you can use regular local variables.

---

This happens because Python is dynamically typed. You can also do `print = lambda *args, **kwargs: "hacked!"`, and now you can't `print` anything (`__builtins__.print` to the rescue!).

Answer (score 1):

You have an issue in your slope method. You have a method name of `slope` and you are also setting a `self.slope` with the output, that is causing the issue.